# how do I avoid getting the empty namespace in newly created XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xelement

I am trying to delete then add a pageFooter to an xml document from a different file:

```
XNamespace rep = "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/8.0/";

//remove pageFooter
doc.Root.Descendants().Where(e=>e.Name == rep + "pageFooter").Remove();

//create and load pagefooter from file
XElement pageFooter = XElement.Load(@"C:\pageFooter.xml");
```

and I am getting the empty namespace:

```
<pageFooter xmlns="">
    <contents>
         ..............
```

I tried all of the following to add the namespace to the new element, nothing works:

```
XElement pagefooter = new XElement(rep+"pageFooter"); 
pageFooter = XElement.Load(@"C:\pageFooter.xml");        
//this has no effect

pageFooter.Name = rep.GetName(pageFooter.Name.LocalName);
//this moves the xmlns="" to the next descendant, <contents>

pageFooter.Add(rep);   
//this has no effect

pageFooter.SetAttributeValue("xmlns", rep);
//this results an empty pageFooter
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with your second effort listed.  The moving of `xmlns=""` to the next descendant means that `pageFooter` had the right xmlns, but the rest of its descendants didn't.  Use this:

```
foreach (var d in pagefooter.DescendantsAndSelf())
    d.Name = rep + d.Name.LocalName;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!! What confused me was why only the next 1 descendant got the empty namespace, and not all? I still don't get that part. Can you explain? Thanks again!!

Comment: If a namespace is not explicitly defined, it inherits its parent's namespace.  So before, the xmlns of pageFooter and all its descendants was "".  Then you made your change and the xmlns of pageFooter changed, but all its descendants were still "", which was denoted by adding xmlns="" to the `contents` element.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you do `pageFooter = XElement.Load(file)` you are replacing anything that is in pageFooter with the contents of the file.  Setting the `rep` namespace beforehand will have no effect on the `XElement.Load()`.

Are you sure that the XML file has a namespace for pageFooter?